# Когда можно использовать scope runtime

Tags: java, maven

В каких случаях может понадобиться добавлять такую область для зависимости? Что то не могу представить чтобы либа нужна была только  в рантайме но не в компиляции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую дополнить существующие ответы и уточнить разницу между `runtime` и `compile`.

Область видимости `runtime` *можно* использовать для зависимости, которая используется во время исполнения и не используется при компиляции. Для такой зависимости и *нужно* использовать `runtime`, а не `compile`, по нижеследующим причинам.

### `runtime` — минимальная область видимости

Всегда имеет смысл выбирать минимальную возможную область видимости. Если зависимость не нужна при компиляции и тестировании, то и объявлять её как `compile` не нужно.

### `runtime` исключает жесткую привязку

Иногда нужно запретить обращение к классам зависимости из кода. Например, если разработчики хотят избежать жесткой привязки кода к библиотеке. `runtime`-зависимости недоступны на этапе компиляции, что явно исключает обращение к классам напрямую.

На примере того же JDBC: библиотека драйвера содержит классы, специфичные для реализации (например, [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html)). Разработчики решают использовать только стандартные классы (`java.sql`), чтобы в дальнейшем адаптировать код для других СУБД. В этом случае `<scope>runtime</scope>` позволяет гарантировать, что к классам драйвера нельзя будет обратиться напрямую.

### `runtime` не мусорит в classpath

Если объявить такую зависимость как `compile`, то вся иерархия транзитивных зависимостей будет добавляться в `classpath` при компиляции как самого проекта, так и всех проектов от него зависящих.

Наличие ненужных классов в `classpath` нежелательно, т.к. это увеличивает вероятность ошибки, усложняет работу подсказок в среде разработки и снижает скорость компиляции.

Comment: Все разъяснили, спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Когда классы загружаются в рантайме. Любая реализация JDBC.

В коде идет работа исключительно со стандартными интерфейсами. А при запуске `DriverManager` в рантайме подгружает нужные пакеты.

Comment: Только в случаях когда я загружаю через class.forname()? В чем проблема использовать тот же compile?

Answer (score 0):

Зависимость в рантайме означает, что зависимость/библиотека уже доступна в рантайме, обычно это касается серверных штучек. Достаточно типичный пример Servlet API уже доступен в любом сервлет контейнере и приложению нет необходимости "таскать" его с собой.

В таких случаях его надо объявлять *runtime provided*. Можно и не делать этого, но в этом случае может возникнуть коллизия версий, скажем, вы положили в jar/war/ear/zip приложения библиотеку одной версии, а в в рантайме уже доступна другая версия.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что это про `<scope>provided</scope>`, а не про `<scope>runtime</scope>`? Не совсем понял что означает *runtime provided*.